# Selecting values from column defined by aggregate function

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently struggling with a query and need some help with it.

I've got two tables:

```
messages {
   ts_send,
   message,
   conversations_id
}

conversations {
   id
}
```

I want to select the messages having the latest ts_send from each conversation.
So if I got 3 conversations, I would end up with 3 messages.

I started writing following query but I got confused how I should compare the max(ts_send) for each conversation.

```
SELECT c.id, message, max(ts_send) FROM messages m
JOIN conversations c ON m.conversations_id = c.id
WHERE c.id IN ('.implode(',', $conversations_ids).')
GROUP by c.id
HAVING max(ts_send) = ?';
```

Maybe the query is wrong in general, just wanted to share my attempt.

Comment: Could you share a sql friddle with the table structure and some data?  The IN is wrong that's PHP code in it.

Comment: Also, I don't think you need a `JOIN` here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT c.id, m.message, m.ts_send
FROM conversations c LEFT JOIN messages m 
    ON c.id = m.conversations_id
WHERE m.ts_send = 
    (SELECT MAX(m2.ts_send) 
    FROM messages m2 
    WHERE m2.conversations_id = m.conversations_id)
```

The LEFT JOIN ensures that you have a row for each conversation, whether it has messages or not. It may be unnecessary if that is not possible in your model. in that case:

```
SELECT m.conversations_id, m.message, m.ts_send
FROM messages m 
WHERE m.ts_send = 
    (SELECT MAX(m2.ts_send) 
    FROM messages m2 
    WHERE m2.conversations_id = m.conversations_id)
```

Comment: Unnecessary `JOIN`... The `conversations_id` is also included in the `messages`-table.

Comment: Edited the answer to explain the use of JOIN. I agree it may be unnecessary in this case.

Comment: Thanks! In my case a conversation cannot exist without a message so I do not need to LEFT JOIN. I just added my IN statement at the end in addition to the WHERE m.ts_send

Comment: **N.B.**: the correlated subquery approach (as demonstrated in this answer) can make for (what we refer to in our shop as) an LDQ (a light dimming query) with large sets, because of the way that subquery gets re-executed for each and every row in the outer query. The performance difference isn't noticeable on small sets, but it becomes very noticeable on huge sets. We usually get better performance with a JOIN operation, as demonstrated in the answer (+1) from GarethD.

Answer (score 3):

MySql optimises JOINs much better than correlated subqueries, so I'll walk through the join approach.

The first step is to get the maximum `ts_send` per conversation:

```
SELECT  conversations_id, MAX(ts_send) AS ts_send
FROM    messages
GROUP BY conversations_id;
```

You then need to `JOIN` this back to the messages table to get the actual message. The join on conversation_id and MAX(ts_send) ensures that only the latest message is returned for each conversation:

```
SELECT  messages.conversations_id,
        messages.message,
        Messages.ts_send
FROM    messages
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  conversations_id, MAX(ts_send) AS ts_send
            FROM    messages
            GROUP BY conversations_id
        ) MaxMessage
            ON MaxMessage.conversations_id = messages.conversations_id
            AND MaxMessage.ts_send = messages.ts_send;
```

The above should get you what you are after, unless you also need conversations returned where there have been no messages. In which case you will need to select from `conversations` and LEFT JOIN to the above query:

```
SELECT  conversations.id,
        COALESCE(messages.message, 'No Messages') AS Message,
        messages.ts_send
FROM    conversations
        LEFT JOIN
        (   SELECT  messages.conversations_id,
                    messages.message,
                    Messages.ts_send
            FROM    messages
                    INNER JOIN
                    (   SELECT  conversations_id, MAX(ts_send) AS ts_send
                        FROM    messages
                        GROUP BY conversations_id
                    ) MaxMessage
                        ON MaxMessage.conversations_id = messages.conversations_id
                        AND MaxMessage.ts_send = messages.ts_send
        ) messages
            ON messages.conversations_id = conversations.id;
```

---

**EDIT**

The latter option of selecting all conversations regardless of whether they have a message would be better achived as follows:

```
SELECT  conversations.id,
        COALESCE(messages.message, 'No Messages') AS Message,
        messages.ts_send
FROM    conversations
        LEFT JOIN messages
            ON messages.conversations_id = conversations.id
        LEFT JOIN
        (   SELECT  conversations_id, MAX(ts_send) AS ts_send
            FROM    messages
            GROUP BY conversations_id
        ) MaxMessage
            ON MaxMessage.conversations_id = messages.conversations_id
            AND MaxMessage.ts_send = messages.ts_send
WHERE   messages.ts_send IS NULL
OR      MaxMessage.ts_send IS NOT NULL;
```

Thanks here goes to [spencer7593](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107744/spencer7593), who suggested the above solution.

Comment: Thanks for the effort and nice explonation!

Comment: +1. a `JOIN` operation usually outperforms an `IN (subquery)`, though we don't really notice that until we start dealing with large sets.  Also, the last query (to get conversations that don't have any related messages), that can actually be done without the addition of an extra inline view. The `FROM messages INNER` can be changed to `FROM conversations LEFT JOIN ON () LEFT JOIN () MaxMessage ON () LEFT JOIN messages`  (changing the order of the table and the inline view), without then need for an extra inline view.

Comment: @spencer7593 It can be achieved with two left joins ([demonstration here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ef3b2/2)), however less is not always more, and the introduction of the required where clause is likely to decrease performance. I only have SQLFiddle available to test the query in MySQL, but in SQL-Server (I know not directly comparable), the two left joins, as opposed to the approach I posted actually has 2 less scan counts (6 and 8), and 12 less logical reads (24 - 36) on [this example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f7664/2).

Comment: @Gareth: the **big rock** difference between MySQL and almost every other relational DBMS is in how it processes inline views. MySQL calls them "derived tables", which is appropriate because of the way MySQL handles the view definition. MySQL runs the query in the view definition, and materializes the results as a temporary MyISAM table. Then the outer query runs against that. MySQL does *not* "push" predicates from the outer query down into the view definition.

Comment: @GarethD: (i'd +1 again if i could).  In MySQL, this query would run an execution plan most equivalent to a SQL server plan for: "create temporary table MaxMessage", "insert into MaxMessage select ...", "create temporary table messages", "insert into messages select from MaxMessage join", "select from messages join conversations...", "drop temporary tables".  (We see DERIVED in the select_type column of th explain output in your SQL Fiddle. One query has one DERIVED table, the other has two.)

Comment: @spencer7593 I've added that solution to the answer, My experience of optimising MySql queries is very limited, and your explanation of how it processes views is a lesson to me, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you would just like the largest `ts_send` from each unique `conversations_id`, you can use this code:

```
SELECT *
  FROM messages
 WHERE CONCAT(conversations_id, '_', ts_send) IN (   SELECT CONCAT(conversations_id, '_', MAX(ts_send))
                                                       FROM messages
                                                   GROUP BY conversations_id );
```

[SQL-fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3623a/1/0)

What this code does is, it creates pairs of the `conversations_id`, together with the largest `ts_send`. It then compares that to all pairs in the entire table.

Comment: Really nice query, if I could accept two answers I would accept yours as well but since the approach from trogdor was already what I need I accepted his answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT c.id, m.message, m.ts_send
FROM
messages m, conversations c,
(SELECT conversations_id, MAX(ts_send) as ts_send 
from messages 
group by conversations_id) s
where s.conversations_id=m.conversations_id and s.ts_send=m.ts_send and 
c.id=m.conversations_id
```

Comment: I've upvoted as essentially this is the same solution as mine, but it is promoting the use of ANSI 89 join syntax which is over 20 years out of date. [This article](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) may be worth a read.

Comment: Thanks for the vote, I will steer clear of the ANSI 89 join syntax from now on ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are saying.

```
mysql> create table messages (ts_send int, message char(30), id int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> create table conversations (id int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

Now some data.

```
    mysql> insert into conversations values ( 1), (2), (3), (4);
    Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)
    Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0


    mysql> insert into messages values ( 4, 'abc', 1 ), 
(5, 'pqr', 1), 
(4, 'abc', 2), 
(5, 'abc', 3), 
(6, 'abc', 4);
    Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.01 sec)
    Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

And then the query.

```
    mysql> select messages.id, message, ts_send 
from messages 
where ROW(id, ts_send) in 
(select messages.id, max(ts_send) 
from messages, conversations 
where messages.id = conversations.id group by id);
    +------+---------+---------+
    | id   | message | ts_send |
    +------+---------+---------+
    |    1 | pqr     |       5 |
    |    2 | abc     |       4 |
    |    3 | abc     |       5 |
    |    4 | abc     |       6 |
    +------+---------+---------+
    4 rows in set (0.00 sec)


     mysql>
```

Right?

*** THIS WAS EDITED to reflect the comment from  Marty McVry.